# Can't exec other programs in a proper way

Tags: c++, execvp

I am trying to execute another program from within my own, but i don't understand a few things. So i wrote this code:

```
void run() {
  cout << "##Run" << endl;
  pid_t process_id = fork();

  if (process_id == 0) {
    char* args[] = {  "sudo", "ls", "-l" };
    auto i = execvp("sudo", args);
    cout << "#Result: " << i << endl;
    return;
  } else if (process_id < 0) {
    throw std::runtime_error("fork() failed");
  } else if (process_id > 0) {
    wait(&process_id);
  }
  return;
}

void run_decorator() {
  cout << "###Run decorator: " << endl;
  run();
}

int main() {
  run();
  run_decorator();
  return 0;
}
```

And the output is

```
##Run
total 88
-rwxr-xr-x 1 bezik bezik 77560 Nov 29 19:53 colors
-rwxr-xr-x 1 bezik bezik    63 Nov 26 21:45 compile
drwxr-xr-x 2 bezik bezik  4096 Nov 26 20:46 headers
drwxr-xr-x 2 bezik bezik  4096 Nov 23 00:48 sources
###Run decorator:
##Run
#Result: -1
```

Can someone please explain to me, why execvp failed when called from run_decorator() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read *carefully* the documentation of [execvp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execvp.3.html). It says about `execl` etc...:

> The first argument, by convention, should point to
>       the filename associated with the file being executed.  The list of
>          arguments **must be terminated by a null pointer**, and, since these are
>          variadic functions, this pointer must be cast `(char *) NULL`.

and regarding `execvp`:

> **The array of pointers must be terminated by a null pointer.**

So you should code:

```
char* args[] = {  "sudo", "ls", "-l",  NULL };
execvp("sudo", args);
```

BTW, `execvp` don't return at all, *except* on failure. No need to keep its result after the call.

But you need, when  `execvp` returns (and this only happens on failure) to show some error message. I suggest:

```
perror("execvp");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

and you could find valid arguments to call, in that precise case, [_exit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/_exit.2.html) instead of [exit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html). I still prefer `exit` (because it would flush the stdio buffers and run [atexit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atexit.3.html)-registered handlers).

> Can someone please explain to me, why `execvp` failed

Yes, [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html). Which is used by [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html).

Don't forget to read *carefully* the documentation of every used function. For system calls (listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)) and standard C library functions (see [intro(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/intro.3.html)), you generally should handle the failure case (often using `errno`, at least thru `perror` then `exit`)

I don't understand why you need `sudo` with `ls`. There are few occasions where that could be useful, since most of the time your [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) is listable (then `sudo` is useless), and in that case you could even use [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html), [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) with [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) (so no need to `fork` then `execvp` the `/bin/ls` program).

Read also about [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) techniques in [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) and [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html) (and [setreuid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setreuid.2.html)). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46782615/841108) (you could avoid `sudo` with your own setuid program).

BTW you should compile [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) all warnings and debug info (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`  with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) and [use the debugger `gdb`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/) (and perhaps [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) and [valgrind(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/valgrind.1.html)).

Comment: Minor note: You're quoting the wrong part of the docs. The part about casting `NULL` to `char*` only applies to the `execl*` family (which are varargs, and therefore don't impose a specific type on the variable arguments, causing problems if `NULL` is just `0`, and thus is `int`-width, not pointer width, or if pointer types aren't constant width for whatever reason). It doesn't apply to the `execv*` family (where a typed array is involved, so `NULL` would be seamlessly implicitly coerced to `char*`). Idiomatically, you want: `char *args[] = {"sudo", "ls", "-l", NULL};`, no need for the cast.

Comment: Thank for your reply, probably tomorrow i will study the documentation again (more carefully this time). 
And answering your question, i don't need  to use sudo with ls, it was just an example.

Comment: It could be the case you don't want `sudo`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46782615/841108